# How to transform depicted object's edges into a logotype

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, logo

I'm new to graphic design.

What I'm interested in is how do I capture the edges of say flower and transform them into a simple logo?

How to do this in Gimp? How to do this in Photoshop?

Comment: You mean you want to make a silhouette?

Comment: Well, I need only the strongest lines not the body of the contour.

Comment: Please, post some example and describe your efforts.

Comment: I second @PaoloGibellini - we need some screenshots. My first thought would be that it would be easiest to create a silhouette, and then create an outline for that. But images would give you better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Pen Tool (p) on photoshop and draw around the outline of the reference, go to the paths toolbar (next to layers tab), right click the path, and click stroke. This will give you the effect you are looking for.

Then it is up to you to make use of it.